# Getting a syntax error on my mysql query around doing math with my where function

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am trying to select from my database of scores only the scores that are 1 and 5, group those scores by the productid and then do some math on those scores to only pull the productids that have a close number of 1 and 5 scores.  My query is below and I'm getting a syntax error on the 7th line, though I'm not sure what the issue is.  Thank you for any help.

```
SELECT title, productid,
       count(*) as total,
       sum(case when score = '5.0' then 1 else 0 end) as high,
       sum(case when score = '1.0' then 1 else 0 end) as low
FROM `reviews`
WHERE total > 0 AND 
WHERE (`high` + `low`)/`total` > '.5' AND
WHERE abs((`high`-`low`)/`low`) <= '.1'
GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: `and where` is not a SQL construct.  Remove all but the first `where`.

Comment: You don't need the second `WHERE`. Just remove it, and the query will work. Voting to delete as a typo.

Comment: Ah makes sense thanks, though now I'm receiving the error: Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query appears to be the `and where`.  That doesn't exist in SQL.  The following is another way to write your query:

```
SELECT title, productid, count(*) as total,
       sum(score = 5.0) as high, sum(score = 1.0) as low
FROM `reviews`
WHERE total > 0 AND 
      (`high` + `low`)/`total` > 0.5 AND abs((`high`-`low`)/`low`) <= 0.1
GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Some notes about this query:

- This simplifies the `sum()` but not using `case`.  The `case` is correct and fine to use.  MySQL happens to support the above syntax because booleans are treated as integer, as they are in the C and C++ languages (0 = false, 1 = true).
- Numeric constants do not need to be in single quotes.  I think putting them in single quotes is a bad idea because it is misleading.
- You have equality comparisons to values that might be floating point numbers.  This is dangerous.  If your columns are declared as decimals, then it should be okay (decimals are fixed point representation).

For the last point, you might consider:

```
sum( abs(score - 5.0) < 0.0001 )
```

Or something similar to handle values that are very close to 5.

EDIT:

I hadn't noticed that the columns in the `where` clause area really aliases.  That means you want a `having` clause:

```
SELECT title, productid, count(*) as total,
       sum(score = 5.0) as high, sum(score = 1.0) as low
FROM `reviews`
GROUP BY productid
HAVING total > 0 AND 
      (`high` + `low`)/`total` > 0.5 AND abs((`high`-`low`)/`low`) <= 0.1
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks though I'm now I"m getting the error: Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here:

1. There is only one `where` clause in a query. It's find to add several conditions with `and`s (or `or`s for that matter), but you only need to specify `where` once.
2. If you're comparing numerical results, you need to use a numerical literal (`0.1`), not a character literal (`'0.1'`).

So:

```
SELECT title, productid,
       count(*) as total,
       sum(case when score = '5.0' then 1 else 0 end) as high,
       sum(case when score = '1.0' then 1 else 0 end) as low
FROM `reviews`
WHERE total > 0 AND 
WHERE (`high` + `low`)/`total` > 0.5 AND
      abs((`high`-`low`)/`low`) <= 0.1
GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY total DESC;
```